# Is it possible to see events from a USB stick

Tags: events, usb

Is it possible to see the events from a USB stick? I live with others, and I had two important files on there. One has been deleted.

Comment: check the log files ... why are you not asking how to recover a deleted file?

Comment: Where are the log files? Because I have asked elsewhere how to recover it on OSx.

Comment: why is there no mention of OSx in the post above? ... linux has logs at /var/log ... maybe OSx is similar ... you may be able to find when the USB stick was plugged in

Comment: I'm not sure it would have been plugged into my device? I'm assuming someone else has used it, and deleted the files. Should have also mentioned this.

Comment: you could check the timestamps on all the files ... see if any coincide with anyone having unrestricted access ... otherwise you are out of luck

Comment: Can you check beyond the last timestamps. Eg. I opened the only other folder, and it's changed the last opened date. I should have checked before doing this.

Comment: look at all possible timestamps ... i do not know much about OSx ... look for any "last updated" timestamps  if there is such a thing ... also look for any backup files that may have been created